# Why does the application not see the .env file

Tags: python

I have the following working directory.

But my application doesn't see the .env file, what's the problem? Here is a screenshot of the directory: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmkXN.png

Here is my code to connect to database using .env

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

load_dotenv()

DB_USER = os.getenv("DB_USER")
DB_PASSWORD = os.getenv("DB_PASSWORD")
DB_HOST = os.getenv("DB_HOST")
DB_PORT = os.getenv("DB_PORT")
DB_NAME = os.getenv("DB_NAME")

try:
    engine = create_engine(
        f"postgresql://{DB_USER}:{DB_PASSWORD}@{DB_HOST}:{DB_PORT}/{DB_NAME}"
    )
    Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine)) 
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Failed to connect to database: {e}")
```

Comment: How do you know that it doesn't load it? How do you execute this code?

Comment: I have an error: Failed to connect to database: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'None'

Comment: Where does that come from? You are not using int() anywhere.

Comment: I don't know why I get this error, but when I do print(DB_HOST(or others)), it comes out none

Comment: Okay, and you think that `load_dotenv()` should have changed the environment variables based on the `.env` file. How do you know that it looks for the file in the directory where you have placed the file?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.